# Do I have to make a minimum payment to my credit card even if the balance is $0 after redeeming rewards?

Tags: credit-card, reward-program, minimum-payment, balance

Let's say this month I spent $50 with the card. The statement comes at the end of the month with a $50 balance and a $30 minimum payment required. Let's say I redeem my rewards on the card, which brings my $50 balance to $0.

You would think that now that the balance is $0, I wouldn't have to make any payment; but if you look at the fine print, most credit cards warn you that "rewards redeemed as a statement credit are not considered a payment".

So, do I still have to make a minimum payment even though that would bring my balance down to negative dollars?

Comment: Does *your* credit card's fine print state that "rewards redeemed as a statement credit are not considered a payment"?  If so, that answers your question.

Comment: It could also be argued that OP's agreement sets out the minimum payment in such a way that if your balance is zero, the minimum payment is zero. On the other hand, if OP had paid off the amount of the minimum payment with the rewards, he/she would still owe the 5% or whatever of the outstanding balance.

Comment: Definitely a case for calling them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the statement says a minimum payment is due, i'd assume you need to make that payment... just to be on the safe side. If you want to do something else, contact *your* issuing bank and ask about the rules for *your* card -- policies may vary from account to account even within a single bank.